# Conditional Rows Based On Column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In SQL how can I exclude a row based on a value of a column.

E.g. I have a column named as PROJECT_MGR_CODE where value is General Manager
If General Manager exists in the result set, then I would like to eliminate Director and CE which are above General Manager.

If General Manager doesn't exist in the result set, then it should bring Director and if Director doesn't exist, then it should bring CE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assigning a hierarchy level to each row and then check for the highest level:

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (
   SELECT dt.*,
      -- max level over all rows
      MAX(hierarchy_level) OVER () AS max_level
   FROM
    (   
      SELECT T2.*,
         CASE
            WHEN project_mgr_code LIKE 'CE%'              THEN 1
            WHEN project_mgr_code LIKE 'Director%'        THEN 2
            WHEN project_mgr_code LIKE 'General Manager%' THEN 3
            ELSE NULL  -- all other rows
         END AS hierarchy_level
      FROM T2
    ) dt
 ) dt
WHERE hierarchy_level >= max_level -- best match manager
   OR hierarchy_level IS NULL      -- all other rows
```

This logic can easily be enhanced to add more levels.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if this does what you want:

```
select t2.*
from t2
where t2.project_mgr_code like 'General Manager%'
union all
select t2.*
from t2
where t2.project_mgr_code like 'Director%' and
      not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.project_mgr_code like 'General Manager%');
```

This seems to be what you are describing.

EDIT:

For a general prioritization query, use `row_number()` with the information in the `order by`:

```
select t2.*
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (order by (case when project_mgr_code like 'General Manager%' then 1
                                               when project_mgr_code like 'Director%' then 2
                                               when project_mgr_code like 'CE%' then 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: The above works fine, what if General Manager and Director do not exist in the table, then CE should be part of the result.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly this is what you need to do:

QUERY:

```
SELECT *
FROM   T2
WHERE  project_mgr_code NOT LIKE 'Director%'
      AND project_mgr_code NOT LIKE 'CE%';
```

RESULT:

[image]

Based on the comment below then this is what you need:

"If General Manager doesn't exist in the result set, then it should bring Director and if Director doesn't exist, then it should bring CE"

QUERY:

```
SELECT *
FROM   #T2
WHERE  project_mgr_code LIKE CASE
                           WHEN
                              (SELECT COUNT(1)
                               FROM   #T2
                               WHERE  project_mgr_code LIKE 'General Manager%') > 0 THEN 'General Manager%'
                           WHEN
                              (SELECT COUNT(1)
                               FROM   #T2
                               WHERE  project_mgr_code LIKE 'General Manager%') = 0
                              AND
                                 (SELECT COUNT(1)
                                  FROM   #T2
                                  WHERE  project_mgr_code LIKE 'CE%') > 0 THEN 'CE%'
                           WHEN
                              (SELECT COUNT(1)
                               FROM   #T2
                               WHERE  project_mgr_code LIKE 'General Manager%') = 0
                              AND
                                 (SELECT COUNT(1)
                                  FROM   #T2
                                  WHERE  project_mgr_code LIKE 'CE%') = 0
                              AND
                                 (SELECT COUNT(1)
                                  FROM   #T2
                                  WHERE  project_mgr_code LIKE 'Director%') > 0 THEN 'Director%'
                        END
      OR (project_mgr_code NOT LIKE('General Manager%')
         AND project_mgr_code NOT LIKE('CE%')
         AND project_mgr_code NOT LIKE('Director%')
        );
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: If General Manager doesn't exist in the result set, then it should bring Director and if Director doesn't exist, then it should bring CE.

Comment: Updated SQL doesn't return expected result, ideally if General Manager doesn't exist, then Director should part of the result. Thanks

Comment: sorry there is a bug in there

Comment: Currently I have it so that if the GM is not there then its the CE then the Director but you can alter it to get the order that you want